# In Regex, how can I globally replace only the first matching character *after* a matching capturing group

Tags: regex, replace

I want to use regex select the first quote after each instance of img_ in the below code. In this example, it would be the " after the jpg.

I tried using the following regex:

`\(?<=img_.*)"+?\g`

but all the quotes after `img_` in each line were selected, including the quotes around `"533"`. How do I match the quotes after `.jpg` without matching any other quotes?

```
<img class="confluence-embedded-image confluence-content-image-border" height="399" src="img_78.jpg" width="533" />

<img class="confluence-embedded-image confluence-content-image-border" height="399" src="img_78.jpg" width="533" />

<img class="confluence-embedded-image confluence-content-image-border" height="399" src="img_78.jpg" width="533" />
```

I want to avoid using .jpg because that .jpg could be many other thing (.png, .jpeg, etc). I want to get the first quote after `img_` regardless of what come between `img_` and the quote.

I basically want to search in a file using that regex expression and only return the first quote after each instance of `img_`. I'm using the replace-in-file module in nodejs which takes in this regular expression and replaces it with a given expression. I tried the above regular expression but it replaces the entire match.

Comment: Why do you want to only match the quote? What are you trying to do exactly? Eg are you trying to replace it or add some text beside it? And what tool/language are you using, because not many allow a variable length look behind such as what your attempt uses.

Comment: This: (?<=img_.*) is NOT a capturing group, it's a look behind (that does not capture). Do you want to capture 'img_' ?

Comment: If you want to add something at the end of that string I would suggest using a domparser instead. If must using a regex, perhaps use a capturing group instead `img_[^"]*(")` https://regex101.com/r/s0MuG4/1

Comment: I want to add text beside the `"` - basically I want to go from `"` to `")}`

Answer (score 0):

> How do I match the quotes after .jpg without matching any other quotes?

```
\.jpg(")
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/L74L5i/1)

> I want to avoid using .jpg because that .jpg could be many other thing (.png, .jpeg, etc). I want to get the first quote after `img_` regardless of what come between `img_` and the quote.

```
img_.*?(")
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/0cXE6Q/1)

Comment: I want to avoid using .jpg because that .jpg could be many other thing (.png, .jpeg, etc). I want to get the first quote after `img_` regardless of what come between `img_` and the quote.

Comment: Edited my reply with the new requirement, though I wouldn't worry too much about getting it right, nothing that involves regex and html is right.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I avoid matching everything before the quote (i.e. I just want to match the quote without having `img_78.jpg` included)?

Comment: When you say "match", you mean "capture"? Because only the quote is captured.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using terms right. I basically want to search in a file using that regex expression and only return the first quote after each instance of `img_`. I'm using the replace-in-file module in nodejs which takes in this regular expression and replaces it with a given expression. I tried the above regular expression but it replaces the entire match.

Comment: Right, so don't use the match, use the capture. Any regex replace function worth its salt, yes, including Javascript, supports capture-based replacement.